# How to use LogEntries on Angular 2 applications (TypeScript)

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, node-modules, logentries

I have this **`tsconfig.json`**:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "removeComments": false,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "outDir": "dist"
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

With **`dashboard.component.ts`**:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import Logger = require('le_node');
var log = new Logger({
  token:'abcdef-1234-ghijklm-5678-nopqrstuvwxyz'
});

@Component({
    selector: 'dashboard',
    templateUrl: 'app/dashboard.component.html'
})

export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        log.log('Test LogEntries...');
    }

}
```

And run **`npm install le_node --save`** to install LogEntries. When tried to run the application with **`npm start`**, I am getting this error:

```
> sample-app@2.0.0 start /Users/user/Workspace/sample-app
> tsc && concurrently "tsc -w" "lite-server" 

app/dashboard.component.ts(10,25): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'le_node'.
```

Comment: is there any solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

> error TS2307: Cannot find module 'le_node'.

you only installed the *module* not its type definitions. If the module is not written in TypeScript (e.g. like angular) you need to get its types externally. That is what `.d.ts` files are for.

## Fix

Quickfix in a file `globals.d.ts`:

```
declare module "le_node";
```

## More

Covered here : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/migrating.html

Comment: Hi @basarat, thanks for your help but it not worked for me. I have the start project mentioned in _https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html_ and when `npm install`, it builds the `typings` path with `global` (for core-js, jasmine and node type definitions) and  `index.d.ts`. I had tried to declare **le_node** on `index.d.ts` and on `globals.d.ts` but still getting `GET http://localhost:3000/le_node 404 (Not Found)`. I also apreciate if you have other alternative.

Answer (score 0):

A solution that worked for me is just to not use the `le_node` module which is not browser friendly. 
And use the [logentries REST API](https://docs.logentries.com/docs/http-post)

```
@Injectable()
export class LoggerService {
    constructor(private http: Http) {
    }

    public log(level: string, name: string) {
        // https://docs.logentries.com/docs/http-post
        const LOGENTRIES_URL = "https://webhook.logentries.com/noformat/logs/";
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append("Content-Type", 'application/json');
        let requestoptions = new RequestOptions({
            method: RequestMethod.Post,
            headers: headers,
            body: JSON.stringify({ "level": level, "message": message })
        });
        this.http.request(LOGENTRIES_URL + YOUR_LE_TOKEN, requestoptions).toPromise().catch((error) => {
            console.log("faield to send log to the logentries server");
        });
    }
}
```